# A dict subclass instance is empty after initialization

Tags: python, dictionary

I try to inherit a dict class, by implementing some logic during the initialization. To do so I add some of the key-value pairs in `__init()__` method.

However, after initialization, the instance of my child class is always empty.

```
import copy
class my_dict(dict):
    def __init__(self, raw_dict):
        self = copy.deepcopy(raw_dict)
        self['bar'] = raw_dict['foo']


original = {'foo' : 'apple'}
alfa = my_dict(original)
print(alfa)
```

prints empty dict while the expectation would be

```
[{'foo': 'apple', 'bar': 'apple'}]
```

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: What do you think `self = copy.deepcopy(raw_dict)` does?

Comment: by overwriting `self=` you've lost the reference to `self`

Comment: I would expect the it creates an empty instance of (dict) and populates it with key-value pair of the passed parameter object (raw_dict in this case). Omitting deepcopy method does not bring the desired output as well.

Comment: Sorry, but we're going to have to disappoint you regarding your expectations.

Comment: `self` works like any other variable. Assigning a new value to it *doesn't affect the object that it held previously.* The actual new dict object is still what it was; you've just assigned a new value to the `self` variable, which doesn't have any further effect.

Comment: When you are working with __init__ in the dict, you don't need to call copy and deepcopy. You only need to call its superclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the super constructor to do the effect you are looking for:

```py
import copy
class my_dict(dict):
    def __init__(self, raw_dict):
        super().__init__(copy.deepcopy(raw_dict))
        self['bar'] = raw_dict['foo']
```

Comment: As per @AMK, `super().__init__(raw_dict)` appears to work just as well.

Comment: But not in all cases. If you really want the `original` to remain untouched, in general, you need `copy.deepcopy()` to ensure the two are distinct all the way down.